# Use custom model for viewing data

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

everyone.

I've got some tables with data, for example: Content, Menu, Info. These tables don't have any relationships. And I need to edit data from these tables on one view. Somethin like that:

```
----------------------------------------
Content Editor        |Menu editor     |
                      |                |
                      |                |
                      ------------------
                      |Info editor     |
                      |                |
                      |                |
______________________|________________|
```

I can't use multiple models on one view, so I tried to make one big model:

```
public class Management
{
    public Content Content { get; set; }
    public Info Info { get; set; }
    public Menu Menu { get; set; }
}
```

But by this way I can't send data to view by using ToList(). Could somebody say what I should to use or read as example, please?

Comment: "But by this way I can't send data to view by using ToList()"?! what do you want?

Comment: I want to show these data on a view.

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewModel do this:

```
public class Management
{
    public List<Content> Content { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

For whichever property you want a list make the property of `List<T>`.  Above is an example, do that to whichever properties you want to be in a list.

Comment: how do you know he needs a `List<Content>`? where does he state that?!

Comment: I was using that as an example, I am not sure which one he wants, I will clarify.

Comment: I want to send these data on a view to display in textboxes and after edit them and save/